# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 20318: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I try to use Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10 with Pip 20.1.1
I would like to install and use Mitre Attack Joystick Master get from this :
https://github.com/mitre-attack/joystick

I check all file is on Utf-8, using StringGenerator 0.3.0, but nothing works every time the same error when I try to launch the command
[error return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ymB.png)

Comment: You will have to put the code as seen in the screenshot. Looks like some error in your code.

Comment: Please, share your codes and errors in a text format.